# How to send data from a form and add them to existing POST data and connect them in PHP to one Text?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I checked stackoverflow and did not find a answer for this here:

1) Format ID2 it to "000000" six digits, example if the ID2 is 302 then should it be 000302

2) I want to combine the now formatted data  (000302) in    with .$_FILES['file']['name'] in the upload.php file and save the file with this new file name.

I am really lost how to do it.

The file transfer code is not from me. It is a code that is from the internet.

I would be very happy for any help!

This is the in the head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/multiupload.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var config =
    {
        support : "image/jpg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/gif",     // Valid file formats
        form: "demoFiler",                  // Form ID
        dragArea: "dragAndDropFiles",       // Upload Area ID
        uploadUrl: "upload.php"             // Server side upload url
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        initMultiUploader(config);
    });

</script>
```

This in the body section:

```
            <div id="dragAndDropFiles" class="uploadArea">
            <br>
            <span style="padding-left: 20px">To upload more pictures for this item click Browse</span>
            <br>
            <span style="padding-left: 20px">The order of the upload decide the order to show the pictures</span>

            </div>

            <form name="demoFiler" id="demoFiler" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="">
                <input id="ID2" type="hidden" name="ID2">
                <input type="file" name="multiUpload" id="multiUpload" multiple />
                <input type="submit" name="submitHandler" id="submitHandler" value="Upload" class="buttonUpload" />

            </form>

            <div class="progressBar">
                <div class="status"></div>
            </div>
```

This the file upload.php

```
            <?php
            if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "sobimages/".$_FILES['file']['name'])){
                    echo($_POST['index']);
                }
                exit;
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: <input id="ID2" name="ID" type="hidden" name="ID2">
Why are you creating two name attributes ?

Comment: Because I did not realize it until you told me it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` function to convert to desired number of digits. For eg. you can use it like this inside your `upload.php`:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
 $new_id = sprintf( "%06d", $_POST['ID2']);
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "sobimages/" . $new_id . $_FILES['file']['name'])){
    echo($_POST['index']);
 }
 exit;
}
```

Comment: I get always only 00000 as result, I have the feeling that the ID2 is not transported

Comment: @ScoobeedoCool you are using dual names in your input tag `<input id="ID2" name="ID" type="hidden" name="ID2">`

Comment: I changed it, but I still get only 000000 and the name of the picture.  Where is the mistake? I dont find it.

Comment: I tried everything, but I get always the file name "000000testpicture.jpg" if the file name is "testpicture.jpg".

Please can anybody look into the ajax section, there is something wron, but I do not  find it.


BIG THANK  YOU!!!

Comment: Instead of using `<input id="ID2" type="hidden" name="ID2">`, you should use with value attribute `<input id="ID2" type="hidden" name="ID2" value="35">`